# How to use functions defined by web pages in ContentScripts indirectly?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xss, code-injection

Following the [Chrome Extension Developer's Guide](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.htm), I know that,

> content scripts have some limitations. They **cannot**:
>
> - Use chrome.* APIs (except for parts of chrome.extension)
> - Use variables or functions defined by their extension's pages
> - Use variables or functions defined by web pages or by other content scripts

But can I achieve this indirectly or are there any examples for this ?

e.g: the-Injected-Page.html

==========

```
<html>
  <script>
    function blabla(){
    //do something
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

How I can use the method in my content scripts?

Comment: If you want to call methods in the page, you have to inject a <script> tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building a Chrome Extension - Inject code in a page using a Content script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script)

Answer (score 1):

As [方 觉](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027654/how-to-use-functions-defined-by-web-pages-in-contentscripts-indirectly#comment26370218_18027654) said, you must inject your script.

```
var actualCode = '(' + function() {
    blabla();
} + ')();';
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = actualCode;
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
```

But there is a point you should know, `blabla()` is still working on context of the web page, not on your content script, so you may call it but that's all you can do. For example you can't get the return value and use it on your content script. It's not possible.

Comment: I think it is possible.  If your injected script writes the return value to the DOM, then your content script could read it.  But it wouldn't be easy.